# How to delete and/or change an Etsy API v2 key

Tags: etsy

My Etsy API key was compromised and I need to either delete it or change it.

I have checked [Etsy's docs](https://www.etsy.com/developers), SO, and Google, and can't seem to find a way.
I emailed Etsy's support, but it's taking quite a long time to get a reply. I'm worried that I'll start racking up charges soon.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: SOLVED: An Etsy Support Request agent had me verify some info and deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Etsy Support Request agent eventually got back to me. Thad me verify some info and deleted it. I wasn't charged anything.